# easy way to animate images while moving them across the screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to animate a series of images while moving them across the screen.

For animation I am using this code:

```
view.animationImages = animations;
view.animationRepeatCount = 0;
view.animationDuration = 6;
[view startAnimating];
```

While moving the image happens like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(370, 0);
}];
```

When I try to combine them in any way, like putting the [view startAnimating] inside the animateWithDuration-block, it completes the first and then begins with the other animations. I want this to happen at the same time. Are there any easy ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier to create CALayer objects, one per image, and move the layers. To modify the animation duration replace the implicit animation of position property with your own one.